# Assign mutiple aliases to web modules on one server

Tags: python, windows-server-2008-r2, web

I'm currently using Tornado on a Windows Server and looking for a way to create aliases on my network and i want these aliases to be redirected on a different port of my webserver.

Example :

Tornado module "**APP1**" is launched with Python on port **1234**
I need alias "**App1.domain**" to be redirected on **myserver:1234**

Same with **APP2** on **1235**, **APP2.domain** must lead to **myserver:1235**

Is there any ways to do that ?

I've separated those modules and each are relative to the same basis, this may be configured on the main module settings (maybe?) ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Regards.

Comment: No, not really. most alias systems are based on server-level entities (DNS, Host File, AVAHI, etc), and do not go down to the service-level where ports have meaning. This is largely because of the way the Berkley Sockets API handles resource lookups ( 'GetHostAddress()', etc) that separate the jobs of retrieving an IP from a symbol (like a hostname) and determining what port on it to connect to.

Comment: Thanks Franck

DNS aliases aren't supporting port redirection.
As explained on Tornado's docs, i have to configure vHost on Apache configuration file.

Have anyone already done this before ?